# How can I generate dynamic button depends on the amount of data in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I store my data in firebase in this format as you can see below:

```
public class web_view extends AppCompatActivity {
            //for fav
            FloatingActionButton fab;
        
            private WebView webView;
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        
                fab = findViewById(R.id.btn_fab);
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //start
                        String passURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
                        //add wishlist to firebase with auto generate ID
                        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                .getReference().child("Users")
                                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Wishlist");
                        myRef.push().setValue(passURL).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){//show it if complete
                                    Toast.makeText(web_view.this, "Added to wishlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{//just error handler
                                    Toast.makeText(web_view.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        //End send wishlist to firebase
        
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve these data and create button dynamical. For example if user click this "fab_wishL", program will retrieve data from firebase and auto create button. If there is 5 data in firebase, there will be 5 button. Is there any way to auto create the button depend on the quantity of the data in friebase

```
public class search_book extends AppCompatActivity {
        
        //---wishlist
        
            FloatingActionButton fab_wish;
        
        
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_book);
                //wishlist
                fab_wish = findViewById(R.id.fab_wishL);
                fab_wish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(search_book.this, wish_list.class));
                    }
                });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add value change listeners to the database reference child, it will give you the list of data you have there, then you can loop to that data and add buttons at runtime.

Check the link for a better understanding

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data